# Properties about order of a general group

Tags: group-theory

For a group, $G$, is it true that $o(Z(G))\cdot o([G,G]) \leq o(G)$ where $Z(G)$ denotes the centre of $G$ and $[G,G]$ denotes the commutator subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any perfect group $G$ (ie. $[G,G]=G$) with a nontrivial center is a counterexample; take for example $G= SL(2,5)$ (mentionned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group#Examples)).

Comment: I can not see why it is counter example, we get $o(G)\leq o(G)$ which is true. Am I missing something ?

Comment: In ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ we have $|Z(G)|=2$, $|G|=|[G,G]|=120$. so $|Z(G)| \times |[G,G]| > |G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I read "nontrivial" as "trivial". Thanks.